# How to find multicollinearity in SARIMAX model?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, multicollinearity

I am working on Malaria cases vs. Meteorological variables. I want to fit a SARIMAX model using met vars to predict cases. My query is how to find multicollinearity between them (Independent) to consider final model.

And please guide me whether there are any methods (packages) in R to find best combinations (iterations) using met vars (Independents) to predict cases.

Comment: You need to use real world knowledge and theory to find multicollinearity.

Comment: Autocorrelation can result in multicollinearity, which is likely if you are finding such linear autoregressive models fit well. An alternative to examining VIF is to check how close $\det R_{xx}$ is to 0 where $R_{xx}$ is the correlation matrix of the features. This approach has theoretical support since $R_{xx}$ is a Gram matrix with a known relationship to colinearity. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575184/how-does-perfect-multicollinearity-affect-r2-and-r-textadj2/575221#575221).

Answer (score 0):

`usdm` package: [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/usdm/versions/2.1-7).

`vif()` is a function to test for multicollinearity.

`vifcor()` and `vifstep()` are two functions which work to minimize overall collinearity through stepwise exclusion.  They are not particularly efficient, so be patient while they run, but it should be what you are looking for.

You may also want to consider the phenomenon of autocorrelation in your analysis.  Since you are looking at time series data (most likely) you will want to not only search for multicollinearity (covariate interaction) but also autocorrelation (self-correlation through time).

Comment: is this for time series data?

Comment: It can be loosely applied, yes.  However, one should also consider autocorrelation in the analysis.  I will edit my post.

Comment: Yes this is time series data having 16 years with monthly values