# How does perfect multicollinearity affect $R^2$ and $R_{\text{adj}}^2$?

Tags: multicollinearity, fitting, estimators

I'd like to know how does perfect collinearity affect measures of fit (R squared and R squared adjusted). A mathematical approach is not necessary, just the general intuition is fine.

Comment: "Affect" in what sense?  What are you comparing collinearity to; or what might you be varying in your data?  For instance, if you have one set of collinear explanatory variables and another set that are not collinear, then the two situations are not inherently comparable: they are different data.

Comment: OP: What do *you* mean by "perfect multicollinearity"?

Answer (score 0):

## Relate multiple $R^2$ to $\det (R_{xx})$

Let us consider the coefficient of multiple correlation $R^2$ for a multiple linear regression. It is defined by

$$R^2 \triangleq \mathbf{c}^T R^{-1}_{xx} \mathbf{c}$$

where $R_{xx}$ is the correlation matrix between all pairs of predictor variables, and $\mathbf{c}$ is a vector of the correlations between the predicted variable and each predictor variable in an order that matches the ordering in the correlation matrix.

Like any invertible matrix, we can note that

$$R^{-1}_{xx} = \frac{1}{\det ( {R_{xx}})} \operatorname{adj}R_{xx}$$

where $\det (R_{xx})$ is the determinant of the correlation matrix and $\operatorname{adj}R_{xx}$ is the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of the correlation matrix.

Taking $$\phi := \mathbf{c}^T \operatorname{adj}R_{xx} \mathbf{c}$$

we quickly obtain

$$R^2 = \frac{\phi}{\det (R_{xx})}.$$

## Relate determinant of $R_{xx}$ to linear dependence

Consider that $R_{xx}$ is a [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) so its determinant is a [Gram determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix#Gram_determinant). A collection of vectors (i.e. our random variables for this intent and purpose) as linearly dependent [if-and-only-if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) their Gram determinant is zero.

## Definition of multicollinearity

(Perfect) [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) is the linear dependence of a collection of random variables.

## Conclusion

Your predictor variables are multicollinear whenever $\det (R_{xx}) = 0$, and when that happens your $R^2$ is undefined.

## Update

I probably made an incorrect assumption that the OP wanted to know about the multiple $R^2$ rather than the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) more broadly. See wikipedia:

> There are several definitions of $R^2$ that are only sometimes equivalent. One class of such cases includes that of simple linear regression where $r^2$ is used instead of $R^2$. When only an intercept is included, then $r^2$ is simply the square of the sample correlation coefficient (i.e., r) between the observed outcomes and the observed predictor values. If additional regressors are included, $R^2$ is the square of the coefficient of multiple correlation. In both such cases, the coefficient of determination normally ranges from 0 to 1.

If someone can offer a broader answer, I am sure we would all appreciate it.

Comment: Re the conclusion: I think it's incorrect.  Collinearity means not all the parameters are identifiable, but it doesn't mean it's impossible to predict values; and when it's possible to predict values, $R^2$--being directly related to the correlation between predictions and actual responses--certainly is defined.  The erroneous conclusion can be traced to your use of a formula that makes sense only when the determinant is nonzero.  A different formula is needed in the singular case.

Comment: @whuber I had not thought about it in terms of identifiability, and perhaps that is fruitful way to think about it. I am not sure if we are using the same definition of "multicollinear" here, so I appreciate the comment pointing out that it may be defined otherwise.

Comment: @whuber I had not considered that there could be a formula for the singular case. I took it as a definition, but I will look to see if I can find a more rigorous source.

Comment: I agree with your characterizations.  Most of the world refers to "perfect mulicollinearity" as *collinearity,* pure and simple, and that's consistent with your use of the terms.  There are several equivalent general definitions of $R^2.$ One is the one I quoted; another is that it's the proportional reduction from the marginal variance of the responses to the variance of the model residuals: that works for *any* kind of regression model, linear or nonlinear, and can fail only when all the responses are equal.